# How to set number of copies for every page by value in Ireport?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jasper-reports

Is it possible to set number of copies for page?

For example:

> SELECT NAME, TYPE, QUANTITY FROM INFORMATIONS

SQL result:

> Tom  | house | 2
>
> Mark| cars   |   3

One page is for Tom and second page is for Mark.

Can i write SQL that will output me that many results as i want. (some for loop?)

I want to see in preview 2 pages for Tom(copies) and 3 pages for Mark. (5 pages to print)

Please, if you can past me sample code or pictures how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate rows based on the quantity, you can do:

```
select i.*, generate_series(1, i.quantity) as n
from informations i;
```

This seems to be what you asking.